# MySQL database creation with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to configure hibernate programmatically and generate database schema and tables in MySQL. Here is the hibernate configuration

```
 configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect")
            .setProperty(AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ritm?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
            .setProperty(AvailableSettings.USER, "root")
            .setProperty(AvailableSettings.PASS, "gjnjkjr")
            .setProperty(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .setProperty(AvailableSettings.POOL_SIZE,"1");
```

When I run it with maven I got the following WARN

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

and after that the exception

```
апр 04, 2013 10:31:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
апр 04, 2013 10:31:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:67)
```

Can anybody describe this?

Comment: Can you connect to the database with plain jdbc?

Comment: If schema already created - yes, if not created then no. I think the problem is it the last url property createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, but I don't understand why it doesn't create schema.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending a port number to the URL. I know it seems silly, however, database communications rely on port numbers and I have noticed that you did not include a port number with the URL. For example, if you are using MySQL, the port number is 3306. Therefore the JDBC URL would look like the following:

```
AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ritm?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
```